# Office taskpane not displaying properly

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

so I was trying to run my custom Officejs add-in after a while and noted that the certificates had expired, and the app wasn't running. So I did a `npx office-addin-dev-certs install` which resolved, however now I notice that the Taskpane is no longer displaying properly (with a dark background, and distorted when dragged). Please see screenshot.
[image]

When I open the app and load the `https://localhost:3000` in the browser it loads up properly without this issue. I also tried [clearing the cache for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) multiple times but didn't fix it. I have not made any edits to the code so not sure how this occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I had the same issue the other day. My solution was to set the background color on the html- and body-tag. Current state of office add-ins is horrible.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="antialiased h-full bg-white">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>LptWord</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body class="antialiased relative h-full bg-white">
  <taskpane-root></taskpane-root>
</body>

</html>
```